# Downloading Vulnerabilities from the NVD by a product name

Tags: java

By visiting http://nvd.nist.gov/download.cfm # XML,

I realized that NIST Provides XML feeds, free for use.

is there a way that enables me to download all vulnerabilities by a product name.

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 0):

http://nvd.nist.gov/download.cfm#CVE_FEED

Is this is not the one you are looking for?